# refresh a parent page when child window is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I refresh a parent page when its child window is closed?

Answer (score 5):

You'll have a script like this in the child.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function refreshParent() {

//re-set the parent url to refresh
//window.opener references the parent page

  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

}

</script>

 [...]

 // the onunload event fires when the child page is closed
<body onunload=refreshParent(); >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the given code in child window:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="butColSmall" 
onclick="btnCancel_Click" />
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "sCancel", "window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;self.close()", true);
    }
```

Comment: This also works except the situation when the child page is closed using the X button or using close tab/page from the browser.

Comment: Yeah! u r right.there are different ways to implement this task.Now its depends on user how they want to do this task.